# Docker-compose build contains invalid type, it should be an array

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

I am trying to build this docker on google cloud but get an error from the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services: 
    mqtt:
        build: ./MQTT
        ports:
            -"1883:1883"
        volumes: 
            -"./MQTT/app/mosquitto.conf:/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf"

    message_router:
        build: ./message_router
        enviroment:
            -MQTT_SERVER_ADDRESS==34.141.97.243
            -MQTT_SERVER_PORT=1883
            -PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

        volumes:
         -"./message_router/app:/etc/usr/src/app"
```

But i get this error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.mqtt.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be an array
services.message_router.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be an array
services.mqtt.ports contains an invalid type, it should be an array
Unsupported config option for services.message_router: 'enviroment'
```

I already tried writing this but get the same error:

```
ports:
    -["1883:1883"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a syntax error in your YAML. Array entries need an empty space after the dash prefix:

```
ports:
    - "1883:1883"
```